# How to generate redirect URI for Smartsheet to pass data to Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, uri, smartsheet-api-2.0

[Screenshot of smartsheet and google setup screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMdp0.png)

When attempting to get data out of Smartsheet, I'm encountering an error that says the redirect URI is missing or invalid when I follow the link that was logged by my apps script project.

I've generated a client ID and client secret on both google and smartsheet but I don't know what to do next.

Google Credentials:
I'm not sure what to put in the redirect Url section or the authorized Javascript origins at the link below.

https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/########################2d.apps.googleusercontent.com?project=project-id-##############

Smartsheet Credentials:
I have activated my Smartsheet Developer profile and generated a client ID and client secret for my app that I've called 'Google Sheets'

Shown below is the code that I have right now which I found on gitHub.

```
var CLIENT_ID = '...'; // what do I put here?
var CLIENT_SECRET = '...';  // what do I put here?

/**
* Authorizes and makes a request to the Smartsheet API.
*/
function run()
{
    var service = getService();
    if (service.hasAccess())
    {
        var url = 'https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/users/me';
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,
        {
        headers:
        {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()
        }
        });
        var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
        Logger.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
    }
    else
    {
        var authorizationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl();
        Logger.log('Open the following URL and re-run the script: %s', authorizationUrl);
    }
}

/**
* Reset the authorization state, so that it can be re-tested.
*/
function reset()
{
    getService().reset();
}

/**
* Configures the service.
*/
function getService()
{
    return OAuth2.createService('Smartsheet')
    // Set the endpoint URLs.
    .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://app.smartsheet.com/b/authorize')
    .setTokenUrl('https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/token')

    // Set the client ID and secret.
    .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
    .setClientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET)
    // Set the name of the callback function that should be invoked to
    // complete the OAuth flow.
    .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')
    // Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
    .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())
    // Scopes to request
    .setScope('READ_SHEETS')
    // Set the handler for adding Smartsheet's required SHA hash parameter to
    // the payload:
    .setTokenPayloadHandler(smartsheetTokenHandler);
}

/**
* Handles the OAuth callback.
*/
function authCallback(request)
{
        var service = getService();
        var authorized = service.handleCallback(request);
    if (authorized)
    {
        return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Success!');
    }
    else
    {
        return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Denied.');
    }
}

/**
* Adds the Smartsheet API's required SHA256 hash parameter to the access token
* request payload.
*/
function smartsheetTokenHandler(payload)
{
    var codeOrRefreshToken = payload.code ? payload.code : payload.refresh_token;
    var input = CLIENT_SECRET + '|' + codeOrRefreshToken;
    var hash = Utilities.computeDigest(
        Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.SHA_256, input, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8);
    hash = hash.map(function(val)
    {
        // Google appears to treat these as signed bytes, but we need them
        // unsigned.
        if (val < 0)
        {
            val += 256;
        }
        var str = val.toString(16);
        // pad to two hex digits:
        if (str.length == 1)
        {
            str = '0' + str;
        }
        return str;
    });
        payload.hash = hash.join('');
        // The Smartsheet API doesn't need the client secret sent (secret is verified
        // by the hash).
    if (payload.client_secret)
    {
        delete payload.client_secret;
    }
    return payload;
}

/**
* Logs the redict URI to register.
*/
function logRedirectUri()
{
    Logger.log(OAuth2.getRedirectUri());
}



function dataHandler(thing)
{
    thing = getData2();
    var rowTemp = thing.split(','), i, j, chunk = 7, rows = [];
for (i=0,j=rowTemp.length; i<j; i+=chunk)
{
    for(var k = 0; k<2; k++)
    {
    rowTemp[k+2] = new Date(rowTemp[k+2])
    }
    rows.push(rowTemp.slice(i,i+chunk));
}
Logger.log(rows);
}


var CLIENT_ID = 'SmartSheet Client ID'; // I'm not sure if this is
// supposed to come from google
// or smartsheet
var CLIENT_SECRET = 'Smartsheet Client Secret'; // Same here

/**
* Authorizes and makes a request to the Smartsheet API.
*/
function run() {
var service = getService();
if (service.hasAccess()) {
    var url = 'https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/users/me';
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {
    headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()
    }
    });
    var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    Logger.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
} else {
    var authorizationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl();
    Logger.log('Open the following URL and re-run the script: %s',
            authorizationUrl);
}
}

/**
* Reset the authorization state, so that it can be re-tested.
*/
function reset() {
getService().reset();
}

/**
* Configures the service.
*/
function getService()
{
    return OAuth2.createService('Smartsheet')
    // Set the endpoint URLs.
    .setAuthorizationBaseUrl('https://app.smartsheet.com/b/authorize')
    .setTokenUrl('https://api.smartsheet.com/2.0/token')
    // Set the client ID and secret.
    .setClientId(CLIENT_ID)
    .setClientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET)
    // Set the name of the callback function that should be invoked to
    // complete the OAuth flow.
    .setCallbackFunction('authCallback')
    // Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
    .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())
    // Scopes to request
    .setScope('READ_SHEETS')
    // Set the handler for adding Smartsheet's required SHA hash parameter to
    // the payload:
    .setTokenPayloadHandler(smartsheetTokenHandler);
}

/**
* Handles the OAuth callback.
*/
function authCallback(request)
{
    var service = getService();
    var authorized = service.handleCallback(request);
    if (authorized)
    {
        return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Success!');
    }
    else
    {
        return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('Denied.');
    }
}

/**
* Adds the Smartsheet API's required SHA256 hash parameter to the access token
* request payload.
*/
function smartsheetTokenHandler(payload)
{
    var codeOrRefreshToken = payload.code ? payload.code : payload.refresh_token;
    var input = CLIENT_SECRET + '|' + codeOrRefreshToken;
    var hash = Utilities.computeDigest(
        Utilities.DigestAlgorithm.SHA_256, input, Utilities.Charset.UTF_8);
    hash = hash.map(function(val)
    {
        // Google appears to treat these as signed bytes, but we need them
        // unsigned.
        if (val < 0)
        {
            val += 256;
        }
        var str = val.toString(16);
        // pad to two hex digits:
        if (str.length == 1)
        {
            str = '0' + str;
        }
        return str;
    });
    payload.hash = hash.join('');
    // The Smartsheet API doesn't need the client secret sent (secret is verified
    // by the hash).
    if (payload.client_secret)
    {
        delete payload.client_secret;
    }
    return payload;
}

/**
* Logs the redict URI to register.
*/
function logRedirectUri()
{
    Logger.log(OAuth2.getRedirectUri());
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/external) tutorial about how to use external APIs

Answer (score 2):

I don't know much about Apps Script or the library that you are using, but you need to find the actual callback URI used by Apps Script and register that as the `App Redirect URL` in Smartsheet. It looks like the callback should be in the form `https://script.google.com/macros/d/{SCRIPT ID}/usercallback` (at least according to the library docs). That should issue the redirect which will eventually call your library `authCallback` with the authorization code for the token.

Here's another useful document of the process (but uses Node). https://developers.smartsheet.com/blog/creating-a-smartsheet-o-auth-flow-in-node-js

Comment: Thanks so much! That got me past the point I was stuck on. I may have more questions down the road but I seriously appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

This is a complicated process that I have documented here: https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#third-party-app-development

If you still have questions after looking at this documentation/tutorial section, please keep asking. I'm here to help.

Comment: Ok, I have read through and believe I've done everything necessary but when I open the authorization page it says it's missing or invalid. What can I do to troubleshoot this?